# Prove that $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability to $Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution

My problem:

Let $(U_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence random variables, and are uniform distributed over the unit interval, i. e. $U_k\sim \mathrm{Uni}([0; 1]), k = 1,2,... $. With $Z$ we denote the
Random variable, which is constantly equal to 1, and define

$Z_n:=\max \{U_1,...,U_n\} , n=1,2,...$

Prove that

1. $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability to $Z$, and
2. $(Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $Z$ almost surely.

---

I have no idea how to start. can someone help?

Comment: Hint: $Z_n<\lambda$ if and only if $U_1,\dots U_n<\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1$ you need to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} P( |Z_n - 1| > \epsilon) = 0,
$$
since $Z_n \le 1$ for all $n$, thus
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} P( |Z_n - 1| > \epsilon) &= \lim_{n\to \infty} P( 1 - Z_n  > \epsilon) \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} P(  Z_n  < 1 - \epsilon)\\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} F_{Z_n}(1-\epsilon)\\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} (1-\epsilon)^n \\
& = 0,
\end{align}
for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. The last step stems from the fact that for $U_1,...,U_n$ i.i.d r.vs
$$
F_{\max\{U_1,...,U_n\}}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n F_{U_i}(x) = (F_U(x))^n,
$$
where for $U\sim U[0,1]$, $F_U(x) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $0<\epsilon<1$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(Z_n \le 1-\epsilon)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathsf{P}(U_i\le 1-\epsilon)=(1-\epsilon)^n,
$$
which is summable.

Comment: for 2? i dont understand what youre doing

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma

Comment: ok so you say (1- ɛ )^n < ∞ , so Zn converges to Z almost sure. And if Zn converges almost sure to Z then it converges also in probability. right?

Comment: The equation shows that $Z_n\to 1$ in probability directly.

Comment: ok i think i need more explained steps .. maybe its all obvious for you and others but for me its very difficult to understand, especially when not everything is explained

Comment: For (1) use the equality and the definition of convergence in probability. For (2) use the B-C lemma and note that 
$$
\mathsf{P}(\liminf Z_n = 1)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{k\ge 2}\liminf Z_n > 1- k^{-1}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(\liminf Z_n>1-k^{-1})
$$